# Completing squares, what are the steps: $2x^2-x(5+m)+(3+m)=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, completing-the-square

I have the following equation:

$$2x^2-x(5+m)+(3+m)=0.$$

I want to find values of $m$ but I forgot the completing squares procedures. Can someone please describe this method for this particular equation?!

Comment: Look at the second answer on this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20597/how-to-re-write-completing-the-square-x2x1"

Comment: If you are trying to *solve* the equation, note that by a miracle (?) the left side factors as $(x-1)(2x-(3+m))$. Or else first note that the original equation has $x=1$ as an obvious root. But you say you want to find the values of $m$. That cannot be done just given the equation. Perhaps (in a separate post) you might ask the *real* question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complete the square on the left hand side of your equation, first  factor out the $2$:
$$\tag{1}
2x^2-x(5+m)+(3+m) =2\bigl(
 {x^2-{\textstyle{5+m\over2}} x+{\textstyle{3+m\over2}} }\bigr).
$$
Write down what you want:
$$\tag{2}
 {x^2\color{maroon}{-\textstyle{5+m\over2} x}+\textstyle\color{darkgreen}{3+m\over2}} = (x-h)^2+k. 
$$
Write the right hand side of $(2)$ as
$$\tag{3}
  x^2\color{maroon}{-2 h x}+\color{darkgreen}{h^2+k}.
$$
Looking at  the $\color{maroon}x$ term of the left hand side of $(2)$ with the $\color{maroon}x$ term of $(3)$, write down an equation and solve for $h$:
$$\textstyle
\color{maroon}{-{5+m\over 2} x} =\color{maroon}{-2 hx}\  \Longrightarrow\ h={5+m\over 4}
$$
Now use equations $(2)$ and $(3)$ to find the value of  $k$: 
$$\textstyle
\color{darkgreen}{{3+m\over2}}= \color{darkgreen}{h^2+k}\ \Longrightarrow\ 
k={3+m\over 2}-h^2\ \Longrightarrow k ={3+m\over2}-({5+m\over 4})^2
$$

So
$$
x^2-{\textstyle{5+m\over2}} x+{\textstyle{3+m\over2}}=(x-h)^2+k=
\bigl( x-{\textstyle {5+m\over4}}\bigr)^2 + {\textstyle{3+m\over2}-({5+m\over 4}})^2 
$$
and
$$\eqalign{
2x^2-x(5+m)+(3+m)
&=2\bigl(
 {x^2-{\textstyle{5+m\over2}} x+{\textstyle{3+m\over2}} }\bigr)  \cr
 &=2\Bigl(\bigl( x-{\textstyle {5+m\over4}}\bigr)^2 + {\textstyle{3+m\over2}-({5+m\over 4}})^2  \Bigr)\cr 
&=2\bigl( x-{\textstyle {5+m\over4}}\bigr)^2 +  {3+m }-2\bigl({\textstyle{5+m\over 4}}\bigr)^2.  \cr 
}
$$

Answer (score 2):

In general: $$ax^2+bx+c=a(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2+c-\frac{b^2}{4a}$$

Comment: Thanks, I am still confused about what to do with $m$ in my equation?

Comment: actually you don't need completing squares to solve this equation. You compute the discriminant: $D=b^2-4ac=(-5-m)^2-4*2*(3+m)=m^2+2m+1=(m+1)^2 \geq 0$. Therefore, the solutions of your equation are $x_{1,2}=\frac{-b \pm \sqrt(D)}{2a}=\frac{5+m \pm (m+1)}{4}$

Answer (score 2):

$$x^2-\frac{(5+m)}{2}x+\frac{3+m}{2}=0$$

$$x^2-2\frac{(5+m)}{4}x+\frac{3+m}{2}=0$$

$$x^2-2\left(\frac{5+m}{4}\right)x+\left(\frac{5+m}{4}\right)^2-\left(\frac{5+m}{4}\right)^2+\frac{3+m}{2}=0$$

$$\left(x-\frac{5+m}{4}\right)^2-\left(\frac{(5+m)^2}{16}-\frac{3+m}{2}\right)=0$$